# Set a CSS rule for dynamic class names

Tags: css

I have a Wordpress theme that create elements with dynamic class names. I don't want to mess the PHP code, so I want to make changes only on the CSS.

Every element has a code like this:

```
<dd class="variation-testing">Testing</dd>
```

I tried to use this CSS rule and it should have worked, but it seems that it doesn't applied the element at all:

```
dd.[class^=variation-] {
  width: 48%;
  float: left;
}
```

How can I add a CSS by using the first part of the class only?

**Update**:

The answer was simple and found in the comments. The right CSS is without the dot.

```
dd[class^=variation-] {
  width: 48%;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Try getting rid of the dot after "dd" in your selector.

Comment: You are right. However, every other example I found on web was with the dot. Thank you!

Comment: just fyi, the dot is used to tell the CSS engine you're looking for class matching the following text, however because you're using an attribute selector "[class^=...]" the dot is invalid (e.g. your first selector is looking for a <dd> element that has a class of "[class^=variation-]")

Comment: @ZebRawnsley Thank you. Probably I missed the meaning somewhere in the way :)

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer (not an edit to the question) for future reference.

Comment: @emmanuel I didn't want to take the credits of the answer and was waiting for the dgavian to do it. If he will not do it, I do later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as stated in the comments the carat selector should be used.

```
dd[class^=variation-] {
  width: 48%;
  float: left;
}
```

Here is a reference for CSS attribute selectors:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp